# Это(,) что, твой кот?

Tags: запятые

Почему надо писать так:

> Это что, твой кот? Ты что, с ума сошёл?

а не так?

> Это, что, твой кот? Ты, что, с ума сошёл?

Answer (score 0):

1. Потому что здесь нет **перечислительной** интонации.

Здесь ***ЧТО*** — вопросительно-восклицательное слово  [по Розенталю](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=131#pp131).

Произношение такое:

(1) *Это **чтО,** // твОй кот? Или чей?*

(2) *Это **чтО** // твой кОт?  Так себе котишка, а говорил, что красавчик.*

2. Есть частица ***что ли***, она **обособляется**:

*Это, /**что ли,**/ твой кОт?*  Ничего, симпатичный.